# Sorting by metadata Mongodb's Nodejs driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, gridfs

I'm using Gridfs to store files and allow the possibility of storing the same file but incrementing a version variable in the file's metadata. I'm using gridfs-stream to access the collection.  So I'm trying to get the latest version out of the collection and I know I can use:

```
{sort: [['uploadDate', 'desc']]}
```

but I'd like to sort by the metadata version field that is named '__v'. I'm guessing the format to do that is this:

```
gfs.collection().findOne({'metadata.fd': fd}, {sort: [['metadata.__v', 'desc']]}, function(err, file) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gfs.collection().findOne({'metadata.fd': fd}, {}, {sort: {'metadata.__v': -1}}, function(err, file) {}
```

Comment: I thought findOne only took 3 arguments?  selector, options, callback?  What's the 2nd argument in yours?